# BeautifulSoup: cannot find tag with specific attribute

Tags: python, python-2.7, beautifulsoup

```
[...]
    soup = BeautifulSoup(url) 
    for row in soup.find("table", { "class" : "grid-border-args" }).findAll("tr"):
        if row.find("td", {"class" : "row-label-one"}) != None:
            uur = row.find("td", {"class" : "row-label-one"})
            if row.find("td", {"class" : "object-cell-border"}) != None:
                vakken = row.findAll("td", {"class" : "object-cell-border"})
                for vak in vakken:
                    duur = vak.find("td", {"class" : "object-cell-border"}).attrs["rowspan"]
```

This code renders an error: "'NoneType' object has no attribute 'attrs'"
It is indeed correct that "none" is returned, but I do not understand why, since every 'vak' begins with the td class with the attribute I'm looking for. Example:

```
<td class="object-cell-border" colspan="1" rowspan="4" style="border-right:3px solid #000000;">
<!-- START OBJECT-CELL -->
<table border="0" cellspacing="0" class="object-cell-args" width="100%">
<col class="object-cell-0-0"></col>
<tr>
<td align="left">Lineaire algebra : stelsels, matrices en afbeeldingen</td>
</tr>
</table>
<table border="0" cellspacing="0" class="object-cell-args" width="100%">
<col class="object-cell-1-0"></col>
<col class="object-cell-1-2"></col>
<tr>
<td align="left">D.0.02</td>
<td align="right">3-6, 8, 10-14</td>
</tr>
</table>
<table border="0" cellspacing="0" class="object-cell-args" width="100%">
<col class="object-cell-2-0"></col>
<col class="object-cell-2-2"></col>
<tr>
<td align="left">CARA PHILIPPE</td>
<td align="right"></td>
</tr>
</table>
<!-- END OBJECT-CELL -->
</td>
```

Why does it not let me get the first td-tag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This part would require nested `td` elements with class `object-cell-border`:

```
vakken = row.findAll("td", {"class" : "object-cell-border"})
for vak in vakken:
    duur = vak.find("td", {"class" : "object-cell-border"}).attrs["rowspan"]
```

That is, first you find all `td` elements with that class and assign them to `vakken`. Then, for each such `td`, you search within it to find a descendent `td` with that same class.